# Load Dataset from Dynamically generated Case Class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, reflection, scala-reflect

**What is Needed:**

number of tables in source database are changing rapidly and thus I don't want to edit case classes so I dynamically generate them through SCALA code and put in package. But now not able to read it dynamically. If this works than I would parse "com.example.datasources.fileSystemSource.schema.{}" as object schema members in loop

**What has already been Done:**

I have some case classes dynamically generated from schema of database tables as below:

```
object schema{
case class Users(name: String,
                 favorite_color: String,
                 favorite_numbers: Array[Int])

case class UserData(registration_dttm: Timestamp,
                    id: Int,
                    first_name: String,
                    last_name: String,
                    email: String,
                    gender: String,
                    ip_address: String,
                    cc: String,
                    country: String,
                    birthdate: String,
                    salary: Double,
                    title: String,
                    comments: String)
}
```

Then i have used them as dynamic type to read in Load[T] function in my Loader.scala as below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, Encoder, SparkSession}

class Load[T <: Product: Encoder](val tableName: String,
                                       val inputPath: String,
                                       val spark: SparkSession,
                                       val saveMode: String,
                                       val outputPath: String,
                                       val metadata: Boolean)
    extends Loader[T] {

  val fileSystemSourceInstance: FileSystem[T] =
    new FileSystem[T](inputPath, spark, saveMode, tableName)

  override def Load: Dataset[T] =
    fileSystemSourceInstance.provideData(metadata, outputPath).as[T]

}
```

Now, by using reflect.api I am able to get TypeTag for my case classes.

```
def stringToTypeTag[A](name: String): TypeTag[A] = {
    val c = Class.forName(name)
    val mirror = runtimeMirror(c.getClassLoader)
    val sym = mirror.staticClass(name)
    val tpe = sym.selfType
    TypeTag(mirror, new api.TypeCreator {
      def apply[U <: api.Universe with Singleton](m: api.Mirror[U]) =

        if (m eq mirror) tpe.asInstanceOf[U # Type]
        else throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Type tag defined in $mirror cannot be migrated to other mirrors.")
    })
  }
```

So if i print now my case class type tag I got:

```
val typetagDynamic = stringToTypeTag("com.example.datasources.fileSystemSource.schema.Users")
println(typetags)
TypeTag[com.example.datasources.fileSystemSource.schema.Users]
```

**Problem:**

Need to read these TypeTag or Dynamically generated case classes, to encode my datasets as below:

```
new Load[typetagDynamic](tableName,inputPath,spark,
saveMode,
outputPath + tableName,
metadata)(Encoders.product[typetagDynamic]).Load
```

This is giving me error : **Cannot resolve symbol typetagDynamic**

if used like this:

```
new Load[typetagDynamic.type](tableName,inputPath,spark,
saveMode,
outputPath + tableName,
metadata)(Encoders.product[typetagDynamic.type]).Load
```

This is giving me error : **type arguments [T] do not conform to method product's type parameter bounds [T <: Product]**

Comment: `typetagDynamic` is a value, not a type.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Thanks, yes but I don't know How can i use it for Encoder of Dataset. So trying with this.

Comment: Why can't you call directly `new Load[schema.Users](tableName,inputPath,spark, saveMode, outputPath + tableName, metadata).Load` with static type `schema.Users` without dynamic string `"com.example.datasources.fileSystemSource.schema.Users"`?

Comment: @DmytroMitin that is the whole issue, number of tables in  source database   are changing rapidly and thus I don't want to edit case classes so I dynamically generate them through SCALA code and put in package. But now not able to read it dynamically. If this works than I would parse "com.example.datasources.fileSystemSource.schema.{}" as object schema members in loop.

Comment: `typetagDynamic.type` can't be correct. `new Foo[Bar](...)` can be used if you know `Foo` and `Bar` statically (at compile time). Otherwise you'll have to create an instance using reflection.

Comment: @DmytroMitin can you suggest something how to Otherwise you'll have to create an instance using reflection.? like this you mean but its not working       

val typetagDynamic =stringToTypeTag("com.example.datasources.fileSystemSource.schema.Users")
  
val classSymbol = mirror.classSymbol(typetagDynamic)

val classType = classSymbol.toType
  typetagDynamic.newInstance.asInstanceOf(classType)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222006/discussion-between-vermaabhishek-and-dmytro-mitin).

Comment: Generating code to access it "dynamically" through reflection appears to be quite pointless to me. Why not access the DB "dynamically"? If you're not able to use the generated identifiers of your code for programming, then code generation makes no sense.

Comment: If you really need something like a dynamic repository, I'd use the (dynamic) DataFrame API. On the other hand, a static generator would have the additional benefit of being able to code some parts using the Dataset API, and generated case classes are useful for providing test data for example. So I'd rather trigger the build pipeline including the static generator when the repository changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know a type `schema.Users` only at runtime try to replace

```
new Load[schema.Users](tableName,inputPath,spark,
  saveMode,
  outputPath + tableName,
  metadata).Load
```

with

```
import scala.reflect.runtime
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val currentMirror = runtime.currentMirror

val loadType = typeOf[Load[_]]
val classSymbol = loadType.typeSymbol.asClass
val classMirror = currentMirror.reflectClass(classSymbol)
val constructorSymbol = loadType.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
val constructorMirror = classMirror.reflectConstructor(constructorSymbol)
  
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
val toolbox = ToolBox(currentMirror).mkToolBox()
val encoderType = appliedType(
  typeOf[Encoder[_]].typeConstructor.typeSymbol,
  currentMirror.staticClass("com.example.datasources.fileSystemSource.schema.Users").toType
)
val encoderTree = toolbox.inferImplicitValue(encoderType, silent = false)
val encoderInstance = toolbox.eval(toolbox.untypecheck(encoderTree))

constructorMirror(tableName,inputPath,spark,
  saveMode,
  outputPath + tableName,
  metadata, encoderInstance).asInstanceOf[Load[_]].Load
```

---

> scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: implicit search has failed

You need either:

1. to define an instance of type class `org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder` for `Users` in its companion object (so that the instance will be in implicit scope)

   ```
   object Users {
     implicit val usersEnc: Encoder[Users] = spark.implicits.newProductEncoder[Users]
   }
   ```

or

2. to import instances of `Encoder` for case classes via `import spark.implicits._` but you need to import them not into current local scope but into toolbox-generated local scope, so in this case you should replace

   ```
   val encoderTree = toolbox.inferImplicitValue(encoderType, silent = false)
   val encoderInstance = toolbox.eval(toolbox.untypecheck(encoderTree))
   ```

   with

   ```
   val className = "com.example.datasources.fileSystemSource.schema.Users"
   val classType = currentMirror.staticClass(className).toType
   val encoderInstance = toolbox.eval(
     q"""import path.to.spark.implicits._
         import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder
         implicitly[Encoder[$classType]]""")
   ```

See the whole code:
https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/2cad52c27f5360ae9b1e7503d6f6cd00

https://groups.google.com/g/scala-internals/c/ta-vbUT6JE8

Comment: After debugging alot I am getting following error. In below code.
I think somehow tree got corrupted


    val encoderTree = toolbox.inferImplicitValue(encoderType, silent = false)

    val encoderInstance: Any = toolbox.eval(toolbox.untypecheck(encoderTree))

scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: implicit search has failed.

Comment: @VermaAbhishek It means compiler can't find implicit `Encoder[Users]`. Did you define or import some?

Comment: it is showing same error as before even if i load like below:

import com.example.datasources.fileSystemSource.schema.Users


println(Users.getClass.getName.replace("$","")
//com.example.datasources.fileSystemSource.schema.Users

println(ScalaClassLoader(getClass.getClassLoader).tryToLoadClass(Users.getClass.getName.replace("$","")))

// Some(class com.example.datasources.fileSystemSource.schema.Users)

    val encoderType = appliedType(
      typeOf[Encoder[_]].typeConstructor.typeSymbol,
      currentMirror.staticClass(Users.getClass.getName.replace("$","").toType
    )