# scala- ways to find implicit execution context in use by a scala program

Tags: multithreading, scala, playframework, implicit

I have a scala class taking implicit execution-context parameter, in play-framework based application. At runtime of this play application, is there a way to see list of implicits(along with names) used by a class? Appreciate any input.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Implicit scope is only a compile time concern

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308467/is-there-anyway-in-scala-to-get-the-singleton-type-of-something-from-the-more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348301/in-scala-2-or-3-is-it-possible-to-debug-implicit-resolution-process-in-runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At runtime, you can summon an implicit via `implicitly[T]`, e.g.

```
println(implicitly[ExecutionContext])
```

This probably won't give you the name that context has been bound to.  As for a list, well, at runtime there's at most one instance of any given type in the implicit scope at a point in time (and the same is true at compile time for a given location in the code), so a list wouldn't be much value.